# How to enforce Q_OBJECT macro usage for classes with signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I have a bunch of base classes with defined `Q_OBJECT` macro and derived classes without it:

```
class Base : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // signals and slots
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    // notice no `Q_OBJECT` macro
public:
    // signals and slots
};
```

That works fine, but according to [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT):

> The Q_OBJECT macro **must appear** in the private section of a class
>   definition that declares its own signals and slots or that uses other
>   services provided by Qt's meta-object system.

***Is there any way to stop compilation when `Q_OBJECT` macro is absent for classes which use Qt meta-system?***

PS: I'm using MSVC compiler

Comment: Are you sure you have signals and they work? Slots can work without the macro, if the new (in Qt5) connection method is used (the one that takes function pointers).
Nevertheless it is still recommended to use the macro in _Derived_ as well because there are other features of Qt that depend on that macro, for example the meta-object system (qobject_cast, etc).

Comment: From what i know there is no way to make the absence of Q_OBJECT macro a compile time error (for all the cases, in some cases you get linker errors if that macro is missing). It is totally up to the programmer to decide if the macro is needed or not.

Comment: @Zlatomir yes, they do work and I'm using modern-style connections. And that seems very odd that I can't ensure its presence (I googled). Hence I asked the question here :) It would be awesome to get a compiler warning which I could easily treat as error during compilation

Comment: If you declare any signals/slots etc. in your class definition then you need to run `moc` on the code.  `moc` should (as far as I recall) complain about the missing `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: @G.M. AFAIK `moc` checks not for a macro but for code it generates. And he finds it because base class generated all the necessary methods so `moc` doesn't complain. The problem is that I want the macro to be expanded for my derived class and override the expansion from the base class